# Error following "gcloud app deploy" with a Go app

Tags: windows-10, google-app-engine, gcloud

Windows 10 Pro 64 bit Insider Edition build 16184

Go 1.8.1

I have the following folder structure:

```
/
+ index.html
+ go.html
+ vim.html
+ git.html
+- css
|   + main.css
+- img
|   + forestbridge.jpg
+- main.go
```

My *main.go* file simply contains the following:

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
}
```

My *app.yaml* file contains the following:

```yaml
runtime: go
api_version: go1
handlers:
- url: /.*
script: _go_app
```

The site work in that it serves files, as well as the web content. It also is able to serve the `main.go` and the `app.yaml` which is an obvious security hole.

It seems to me that the obvious culprit for this behaviour is the `http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))` line in the source which is serving anything and everything. How do I fix this?

Another issue, though one of secondary importance, is the fact that I have tied myself into the nonflexible way of doing things which means that I will have to sacrifice Go 1.8 compatibility should my code ever get so advanced. How would I change things to use the `env: flex` approach?

Comment: There are 2 versions of App Engine environments, i.e. Standard and Flexible -- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/.  Looks like most of your code is geared towards Standard.  For Standard, there is no env key-value in app.yaml.  env: flex is meant for Flex.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the issue. A common mistake new users make is to use elements from the wrong documentation (eg. flex elements in a standard config). Can you elaborate on how you're downloading the source code of main.go?

Comment: It seems you're accidentally including your source code as static files and serving them. I'd advise posting a new question showing your app's directory structure and current app.yaml. Please don't edit this question as a new question, as it's not good Stack Overflow etiquette :)

Comment: Why don't you move to a structure that would contain an "HTML" directory and main.go file. So you can serve http.Dir("HTML"). That would prevent serving source code on main directory. Or did I misunderstood the question?